# Metódo constructor libro

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

me asignaron este ejercicio y no he podido resolverlo. Consta de lo siguiente:
Crear un método constructor llamado Libro. Sus atributos título del libro, autor, número de ejemplares del libro y número de ejemplares prestados los siguientes métodos para la clase:

- Préstamo () que incremente el atributo correspondiente cada vez que se realice un préstamo del libro.
- No se podrán prestar libros de los que no queden ejemplares disponibles para prestar. Devuelve true si se ha podido realizar la operación y false en caso contrario.
- Devolución () que decremente el atributo correspondiente cuando se produzca la devolución de un libro. No se podrán devolver libros que no se hayan prestado. Devuelve true si se ha podido realizar la operación y false en caso contrario.
- ToString () para mostrar los datos de los libros. Este método se heredada de Object y lo debemos modificar (override) para adaptarlo a la clase Libro.

Al empezar el código me sale error y no he podido solucionarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `libro` es una función, que podrías usar como constructor de una clase para crear una instancia Necesitarías hacer algo como `let miLibro= new libro(); miLibro.prestamo()`. Pero declarar una clase así es una sintaxis que se considera "anticuada", mira la respuesta de @alejandro00, que declara la clase usando la sintaxis moderna

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo leer [ask]: añade siempre código como texto, no como imágenes, en las preguntas. así podremos copiar y pegar ese código a las respuestas o a nuestros IDE para hacer pruebas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que no estás construyendo una `clase` sino una `función` y por lo que entiendo debería de ser de la siguiente forma.

```js
class libro {
    constructor(tituloLubro,autor,numeroEjemplaresLibro,numeroEjemplaresPrestados){
        this.tituloLibro = tituloLibro;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.numeroEjemplaresLibro = numeroEjemplaresLibro;
        this.numeroEjemplaresPrestados = numeroEjemplaresPrestados;
    }
    prestamo(){
        if(numeroEjemplaresPrestados > 0){
            return `Ejemplares prestados ${numeroEjemplaresPrestados}`
        }
    }
}
```